# Volume growth of balls

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $K\subset G$ a compact subgroup. Suppose that on the homogeneous space $X=G/K$ we have a $G$-invariant proper metric $d$. For $R>0$ let $B(R)$ be the open ball of radius $R$ around the base-point $x_0=eK$ in $X$.
Also, any Haar measure on $G$ induces a $G$-invariant measure on $X$.

My question is:
Which growth rates can occur for ${\rm vol}(B(R))$ as $R\to\infty$?

If $X={\mathbb R}^n$, we can have polynomial growth. If $X$ is a hyperbolic space, we have exponential growth.

My first case of interest is a semi-simple Lie-group $G$, where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup. 
Then there is a natural metric coming from the Killing form. In this case I guess the growth must be exponential. But where can I find precise statements where the constants have been determined? Already the case $SL_n({\mathbb R})$ is unknown to me.

Next the case of a semi-simple linear $p$-adic group would be of interest, where the metric is derived from the metric on the building of $G$.

Finally, putting things together, adelic groups would be the focus, but of course any more general statement (if there is) would be most welcome.

Comment: Yes: non compact semisimple groups over reals or $p$-adics have exponential growth. So the growth of $G/K$ is at least exponential, and is precisely exponential if the metric is reasonable (e.g., has good geodesic properties, such as the Riemannian metric in the real case or the metric induced from the building in the $p$-adic case.

Comment: @YCor: Do your know any references where the growth is computed exactly? Like $\sim Ae^{Bx}$ and the constants $A$ and $B$ are computed?

Comment: No I don't know.